# What is the proper way to use Google Pub/Sub with Flink Streaming using Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, flink-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to run Apache Flink on Dataproc and use Google Pub/Sub as a source/sink. When I create a Dataproc cluster, after applying [flink initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/flink/flink.sh) to the most recent image [1.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un6gB.jpg), Flink 1.6.4 will be installed.

The problem is that [flink-connector-gcp-pubsub](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-gcp-pubsub) is only available starting from Flink version 1.9.0.

So my question is what is the proper way to use all of this together? Should I build my own gce image with the latest Flink? Is there one already existing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by running Flink 1.9.0 in Kubernetes. This way I do not depend on anybody and can run whatever version I need.

Answer (score 5):

As you already said `flink-connector-gcp-pubusub` is only available from Flink 1.9.0. So you have two options:

- Either implement connector yourself
- Build your own image based on the [flink initialization actions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/flink/flink.sh)

I would not recommend implementing connector as it is a complex task and requires an in-depth understanding of Flink while building your own image should be relatively easy given an example for Flink 1.6.4